# GWT JsonpRequestBuilder and codeServer (debug mode) not working in IE8 compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, jsonp

A break point does not reach when I run the GWT app with code server parameter for the debug mode.
This happens only for IE8 compatibility mode, everything works for IE8 standard mode and rest of the browsers.
I am compiling for IE6 and above.

Same problem goes for the JsonpRequestBuilder, request is successfully fired, but never returned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the script below:

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" id='__gwt_historyFrame' style='position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0'></iframe>
```

just before the nocache.js reference.

Comment: What does the history iframe have to do with JSONP script loading? Is there some specific IE8 issue that links these otherwise unrelated pieces of functionality?

Comment: This is IE compatibility mode bug fix. Basically bug was found JSONP script not working. Later on, I discovered that Window.alert(), etc was also not working and saw a warning on dev console to add above script to HTML. After the insertion of script, everything started working.